# Add param to joomla 3 component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

How can I add param to Joomla 3 the component `[com_tracker]`

I added a column to my component table and it has a 0 or 1 value i need to get this col like param

For example:

```
$torrent->mycol
```

that has a value 0 or 1 that reads it from db.

Comment: Usually for parameters you would have a column params and all of the params would be stored in json.

Comment: That's a different issue.  This question is about an existing component.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, don't hack your components. This is a case where you need to create a plugin to add the additional functionality. (plugins to the rescue)

Here is a guide that will walk you through the concept.

https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

Here is good book on plugins if you need more info
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the below method to call your database param in your joomla component.

**1. Fetch single column with specific single value.**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT mycol FROM #__TABLENAME WHERE id="'.$value.'" ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$mycol = $db->loadResult();
```

**2. Fetch single row.**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__TABLENAME WHERE id="'.$value.'" ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow(); // Return with number array key
$row = $db->loadObject(); // Return stdClass Object Array
$row = $db->loadAssoc(); // Return with column name as key in array
```

**3. Fetch Multiple row.**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__TABLENAME ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRowList(); // Return with number array key
$row = $db->loadObjectList(); // Return stdClass Object Array
$row = $db->loadAssocList(); // Return with column name as key in array
```

Comment: Thanks , but how can i create a param???

Comment: You have to add all of the parameters you want into your form's XML file.

Comment: Thanks That Was Helpful